# python: перегрузка сложения и т.д. для родительского класса, но возвращение результата как от дочернего

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, перегрузка-операторов, override

подскажите как корректно решить следующую ситуацию:

есть базовый класс `MyBaseClass` с перегруженным оператором `__add__`

и есть дочерний класс `MyChildClass`, который в конструкторе выставляет свои параметры, а большая часть функций уже от базового класса

в итоге:

```
class MyBaseClass:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return MyBaseClass(...) # тут вычисляю необходимые параметры из self и other

class MyChildClass(MyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # тут устанавливаю необходимые параметры
```

В результате когда я делаю

```
a = MyChildClass(...)
b = MyChildClass(...)

c = a + b
```

то `type(c)` выдаёт, что это MyBaseClass

Вопрос - а как сделать, чтобы это был именно `MyChildClass`?
Без переноса кода в MyBaseClass конечно же иначе какой смысл в базовом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Динамически вызывайте нужный конструктор:

```
class MyBaseClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self.val + other.val)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.val})"

class MyChildClass(MyBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__(val)


a = MyChildClass(1)
b = MyChildClass(2)

c = a + b

print(c)
```